Python: prevent the user from closing the terminal
I'm making a simple python program. This program is started in terminal (windows cmd) from a batch file. The program is an infinite loop, so it never ends.
What I would like to do is prevent the user from closing the terminal and terminating the program abruptly.
I need it because before terminating the program it needs to carry out some cleaning operations, so I would like to somehow intercept the window closing event and carry out some operations.
Can anyone help me

one way i can think of is using SetConsoleCtrlHandler to listen when the console is closing then using FreeConsole to ditch the console altogether, i could write an example when i have the time.

On Unix, you should get a SIGHUP signal when the window is closed. You should be able to write a handler for this.

you can check out how to disable the console X button.
if you just want to clean-up before exit then on windows you can use SetConsoleCtrlHandler in python using pywin32 to set an exit handler, this exit handler will give you about 5 seconds to cleanup before the process abruptly quits.
import win32api
import time

def console_ctrl_handler(ctrl_type):
    if ctrl_type == 2:
        i = 0
        while True:
            print(i)
            i += 1
            time.sleep(1)
        return False
    # Return True to pass the event to the next handler
    return True

win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(console_ctrl_handler, True)

while True:
    pass

if you need more than 5 seconds then you need to

free the attached console
tell other threads to end soon
kill the current thread to prevent it from killing the application

import win32api
import win32console
import time
import ctypes

value = True

def console_ctrl_handler(ctrl_type):
    if ctrl_type == 2:
        ExitThread = ctypes.windll.kernel32.ExitThread
        # signal main thread to end
        global value
        value = False

        # free console and kill this thread
        win32console.FreeConsole()
        ExitThread(0)
        return False
    # Return True to pass the event to the next handler
    return True

win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(console_ctrl_handler, True)

while value:
    pass

now = time.time()

# bussy wait for 10 seconds
while time.time() < now + 10:
    pass

you will notice the console now closes early, but the task manager will still show the process for 10 seconds after the console closes.

the safer method is to just convert your application to a GUI application instead of a console application, easily done in python by using FreeConsole at startup then spawning your GUI of choice.
maybe spawn a tkinter window so you can intercept the exit button to do your cleanup, also make sure you save stdout and stderr to some log file since you will have no console.

If you are using powershell ( Terminal ) the window will close but the process will still be running in the background for the 5 or 10 seconds, and you can see it in the task manager.

both codes you sent me don't work, if I launch them in the Windows terminal, if I close the window the program ends immediately.

@FedericoMassimi if you are using powershell (Windows Terminal) the terminal window will close immediately, but the worker will still be running in the background for the 5 seconds / 10 second, check the task manager to verify that.
